# LaTeX: First page blank

Tags: page-breaking

I just installed LaTeX with TeXworks today. I need to create a simple PDF out of a couple large images, I realize this is likely very crude and roundabout but I somehow managed to get the thing done. However, LaTeX inserts a blank page before the stuff I want, and I can't find a way to get rid of it. I thought it may simply be the title page and tried adding `notitlepage` in `documentclass`, but that's not it. Here's the whole thing:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0pt}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{0pt}
\setlength{\headsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\marginparsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{0pt}
\addtolength{\voffset}{-20pt}
\addtolength{\hoffset}{-22pt}
\setlength{\textheight}{25.8cm}
\graphicspath{{A:/Desktop/pdf/1/}}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.png}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\begin{document}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=17.7cm]{pg1}
\newpage
\includegraphics[width=17.7cm]{pg2}
\newpage
\includegraphics[width=17.7cm]{pg3}
\newpage
\includegraphics[width=17.7cm]{pg4}
\newpage
\includegraphics[width=17.7cm]{pg5}
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I used the demo option for graphicx, and I do not get a blank page in the start of my document using your code.

Comment: Use `\usepackage{geometry}` to set the margin and type block.

Comment: At a guess, I'd say your pictures are bigger than the page size that you've defined.  Try using the `geometry` package to get better control over the page size and make it big enough that your pictures fit on the page.

Comment: @AndrewStacey: this was also my suspicion; @ozu: you can test this very easily if you replace the first `\includegraphics{...}` with `\rule{17.7cm}{35cm}`. When you change the height to a smaller value, e.g. 25 cm, no blank page is generated.

Comment: My pictures are exactly the same height as the page height I defined, and it turns out I simply had to set it a little higher, changing it from `\setlength{\textheight}{25.8cm}` to `\setlength{\textheight}{25.9cm}` did the trick. Thanks a lot! However, I'd like to know why does it work this way. Do the images get some minimal border/margin by default?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Even a tiny difference in the computed dimensions may produce an overfull box. So I suggest another approach: zero margin and vertical centering.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\vcenterincludegraphics}[2][]{%
  \newpage
  \vspace*{\fill}
  \includegraphics[#1]{#2}\par
  \vspace{\fill}
  \newpage
}
\pagestyle{empty}


\begin{document}

\centering

\vcenterincludegraphics[width=17.7cm]{pg1}

\vcenterincludegraphics[width=17.7cm]{pg2}

\vcenterincludegraphics[width=17.7cm]{pg3}

\vcenterincludegraphics[width=17.7cm]{pg4}

\vcenterincludegraphics[width=17.7cm]{pg5}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I already solved the problem somehow, but this is clearly a far more elegant solution, I didn't know you could use `geometry` to set all margins to 0 at once. I guess I should actually sit down and make some effort to learn LaTeX properly instead of trying to stitch a pdf in 15 minutes with no prior experience. Thanks again

Comment: @ozu I think most of us started out my trying to stitch a pdf in 15 minutes with no prior experience ... so you're currently following the tried-and-tested route for learning LaTeX!